# Clone oracle 10g (linux5 32bit) to 10g (linux 6.4 64 bit)

Tags: linux, database, oracle

My Question is this can i create a clone of oracle 10g (linux5 32bit) to 10g (linux 6.4 64 bit)

kindly help

Can i follow this

STEP 1: On the old system, go into SQL*Plus, sign on as SYSDBA and issue: “alter database backup controlfile to trace”. This will put the create database syntax in the trace file directory. The trace keyword tells oracle to generate a script containing a create controlfile command and store it in the trace directory identified in the user_dump_dest parameter of the init.ora file. It will look something like this:

```
STARTUP NOMOUNT
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "OLDLSQ" NORESETLOGS
NOARCHIVELOG
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 2
MAXDATAFILES 240
MAXINSTANCES 1
MAXLOGHISTORY 113
LOGFILE
GROUP 1 ('/u03/oradata/oldlsq/log1a.dbf',
'/u03/oradata/olslsq/log1b.dbf') SIZE 30M,
GROUP 2 ('/u04/oradata/oldlsq/log2a.dbf',
'/u04/oradata/oldlsq/log2b.dbf') SIZE 30M
DATAFILE
'/u01/oradata/oldlsq/system01.dbf',
'/u01/oradata/oldlsq/mydatabase.dbf'
;
# Recovery is required if any of the datafiles are restored
# backups, or if the last shutdown was not normal or immediate.
RECOVER DATABASE
# Database can now be opened normally.
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

STEP 2: Shutdown the old database

STEP 3: Copy all data files into the new directories on the new server. You may change the file names if you want, but you must edit the controlfile to reflect the new data files names on the new server.

```
rcp /u01/oradata/oldlsq/* newhost:/u01/oradata/newlsq
rcp /u01/oradata/oldlsq/* newhost:/u01/oradata/newlsq
rcp /u03/oradata/oldlsq/* newhost:/u03/oradata/newlsq
rcp /u04/oradata/oldlsq/* newhost:/u04/oradata/newlsq
```

STEP 4: Copy and Edit the Control file – Using the output syntax from STEP 1, modify the controlfile creation script by changing the following:

Old:

```
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "OLDLSQ" NORESETLOGS
```

New:

```
CREATE CONTROLFILE SET DATABASE "NEWLSQ" RESETLOGS
```

STEP 5: Remove the “recover database” and “alter database open” syntax

```
# Recovery is required if any of the datafiles are restored
# backups, or if the last shutdown was not normal or immediate.
RECOVER DATABASE
# Database can now be opened normally.
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

STEP 6: Re-names of the data files names that have changed.

Save as db_create_controlfile.sql.

Old:

```
DATAFILE
'/u01/oradata/oldlsq/system01.dbf',
'/u01/oradata/oldlsq/mydatabase.dbf'
```

New:

```
DATAFILE
'/u01/oradata/newlsq/system01.dbf',
'/u01/oradata/newlsq/mydatabase.dbf'
```

STEP 7: Create the bdump, udump and cdump directories

```
cd $DBA/admin
mkdir newlsq
cd newlsq
mkdir bdump
mkdir udump
mkdir cdump
mkdir pfile
```

STEP 8: Copy-over the old init.ora file

```
rcp $DBA/admin/olslsq/pfile/*.ora newhost:/u01/oracle/admin/newlsq/pfile
```

STEP 9: Start the new database

```
@db_create_controlfile.sql
```

STEP 10: Place the new database in archivelog mode

Comment: If you know those steps already (and might be nice to say where you got them, linking if possible, to give credit) then is your question really: are the files, including the .dbf data files, compatible between 32-bit and 64-bit systems? Which 'Linux' is this - Red Hat/OEL, from the version numbers? Do you really want to clone though, rather than creating a new DN and moving the contents with data pump?

Comment: Sir, Here problem is that In existing Database datafiles extantion is not .dbf i think by mistake will be create (.dbs,dff) but database are running properly but when we are creating clone with help of above mention steps.then that are not read another type of file (dbs,dff) this situation can i alter that specific datafile help of "alter command" with mount db. and have any chances of data lose...

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to review tablespace and datafile conversions using RMAN for cross-platform interoperability:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/dbxptrn.htm#BRADV05432